# Prestashop 1.7 Transplant a Module Page Temporarily Unavailable Error

Tags: php, apache, prestashop

I recently started experiencing a strange error every single time I try to visit the transplant a module page. From the design > positions page3 I click on the "transplant a module" button on the top right and it takes a really long time to load, but then it does not load at all. I get a blank page with the following error:

`The page you are looking for is temporarily unavailable.
Please try again later. 
5cb0af3eb5bd6096ecb4dce014d6635a 3a1c22abc23c754c0fb7be3b7c58431e 159cf03490b9d26b556696ed897a7daa`

I contacted my server provider and they explained to me that the server I was using was reaching the max amount of files allocated, and that I needed to get a new server just for this particular site. So I did. I then cloned the site and database and brought it over to the new server....but I'm still getting this error everytime I try to transplant a module.

Any one ever encountered this issue? Any one have any ideas as to what could be causing this? Any suggestions on what I can do to troubleshoot this error further?

I have turned on debug mode, and it does not give any more information than what's above.

Thank you all,

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are facing the following known bug. It will be fixed in 1.7.5 (coming soon)

https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/issues/10811

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes module have some issues, I've a problem one day and this help me :

In config/xml copy the 2 files "must_have_modules_list.xml" and "default_country_modules_list.xml" on your PC in case,

And then delete the two files from your site,

This "refresh" the cache of your module config

Hope will help you

Comment: Hi Thomas, thank you for your suggestion, but that did not work for me :-(

Comment: np :) hope you will find

Answer (score 0):

The "Transplant a module" page is now working after I changed the file **AdminModulesPositionsController.php** in **/root/controllers/admin** folder.

In line 449 changed:

```
$all_modules_controllers = Dispatcher::getModuleControllers($type);
```

to

```
$all_modules_controllers = Dispatcher::getControllers($type);
```

Try this, it's working for me.